# How to get "console.log" from Selenium (with Chrome) in the Rails log files?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-chrome, selenium, capybara, selenium-chromedriver

In Rails project, I'm using Cucumber, with Capybara, in order to run my tests in a Chrome web browser through Selenium.

My tests are running fine but I would like to get the `console.log`, `console.error` and so on in the log files of my Rails application.

I have registered a `:chrome` capybara driver like this (based on different articles and SO answers):

```
Capybara.register_driver :chrome do |app|
  capabilities = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome(
    chromeOptions: {
      args: chrome_switches,
    },
    loggingPrefs: {
      browser: 'ALL',
      client: 'ALL',
      driver: 'ALL',
      server: 'ALL'
    }
  )
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(
    app,
    browser: :remote,
    url: "http://selenium:#{ENV['SELENIUM_PORT']}/wd/hub",
    desired_capabilities: capabilities
  )
end
```

But I have nothing, from the Chrome browser, in the log files.

How to get "console.log" from Selenium (with Chrome) in the Rails log files?

Answer (score 4):

The logs don't show up automatically, you would need to request them from Selenium and then add then write them out to whatever log you like.  To request the logs you need to do something like

```
page.driver.browser.manage.logs.get(:browser) # :driver, etc.
```

Generally you'd do something like that in an after step and then write it to the log file you want it to be in.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I need the logs to be written in the log file as soon as they pop so that in the log file I can see what executed before or after a specific other line. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: @ZedTuX If you are using cucumber you could use an AfterStep block to get the new logs after each step in your feature and write them out (which would be closer to what you're asking but not exactly).  Otherwise there is no way (the webdriver spec doesn't provide any ability for immediate feedback of JS error/console log/etc)

Comment: Thank you Thomas for your comment.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working in most recent versions of the driver (and it did work before).

Comment: @FilipKis This answer is from over a year ago - things change.  It stopped working because chromedriver 75 defaults to w3c mode which doesn't support these methods. Currently you can configure your driver to not use w3c mode but not sure how long chromedriver will support that for.

Comment: Thanks @ThomasWalpole, I had suspicion it's related to w3c webdriver specs and thanks for the tip of disabling it. As it's likely gonna also go away after some time, I'm not keen on using that solution, but would like to find more permanent. Any idea if there's any way of getting JS console logs from w3c mode? Or is that just not possible until w3c updates the specs (probably years from now)?

Comment: @FilipKis Not currently possible in w3c mode.  It looks like Chromedriver 76 or 77 will add the methods back as w3c compliant endpoints, so selenium-webdriver may support it  in w3c mode then.

Comment: @ThomasWalpole has this happened yet? If so: Where can one find more information on that?

Comment: @AlexanderPresber Yes - a long time ago - it's accessible via a driver specific method - https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara/blob/f7ab0b5cd5da86185816c2d5c30d58145fe654ed/spec/selenium_spec_chrome.rb#L185

Comment: *** NoMethodError Exception: undefined method `logs' for #<Selenium::WebDriver::Manager:0x00007f13bc6383b0